Getting only one row of data per primary key when there are many foreign keys that equals it
I have a procedure where I am trying to fetch the only on row of data per foreign key (FK) per (PK) in a table (turning a one-to-many relationship into a one-to-one table).
I have some tables that looks like below. NOTE: my tables do not actually look like this, these are just examples.
COMPANY



CompanyNo_PK
CompanyName




1
Foo


2
Bar


3
FooBar



JOB ROLE



JobRoleNo_PK
RoleName




1
Manager


2
IT


3
Clerk



EMPLOYEE



EmployeeNo_PK
EmployeeName
CompanyNo_FK
JobRoleNo_FK
DateHired




1
Steve
1
1
1/3/2018


2
Bob
2
1
1/9/2021


3
Daisy
3
1
3/7/2020


4
John
1
2
2/9/2019


5
Sam
1
3
5/17/2022


6
Kathy
1
1
6/25/2022


7
Cait
3
3
9/6/2020


8
Adam
3
1
8/3/2021


9
Mario
2
2
4/30/2020



My procedure should output a table using the tables above to only see the MOST CURRENT Manager for each Company.
So the output should look something like this:
CURRENT COMPANY MANAGERS



CompanyName
EmployeeName
DateHired




Foo
Kathy
6/25/2022


Bar
Bob
1/9/2021


FooBar
Adam
8/3/2021



I tried the following query below, but I did not get the result I wanted.
CREATE PROCEDURE [Current Company Managers] 
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        c.[CompanyName], e.[EmployeeName], e.[DateHired]
    FROM  
        [Company] c 
    LEFT JOIN 
        [Employee] e ON e.CompanyNo_FK = c.CompanyNoPK 
                     AND JobRoleNo_FK = 1
                     AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                      FROM [Employee] ee 
                                      WHERE c.CompanyNo_PK = ee.CompanyNo_FK 
                                        AND ee.DateHired > e.DateHired)
                          OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                         FROM [Employee] ee 
                                         WHERE c.CompanyNo_PK = ee.CompanyNo_FK 
                                           AND ee.DateHired < e.DateHired))

I included the OR NOT EXISTS operation since there were cases where some current managers were not being listed in the view when they should be or the managers being listed were incorrect (mainly the older entries).
However, even with that, the results would returns the wrong entries:



CompanyName
EmployeeName
DateHired




Foo
Kathy
6/25/2022


Bar
Bob
1/9/2021


FooBar
Daisy
3/7/2020



I have multiple entries per company:



CompanyName
EmployeeName
DateHired




Foo
Kathy
6/25/2022


Bar
Bob
1/9/2021


FooBar
Adam
8/3/2021


FooBar
Daisy
3/7/2020,



but I'm also missing some entries:



CompanyName
EmployeeName
DateHired




Bar
Bob
1/9/2021


FooBar
Adam
8/3/2021



or some combination of the three. So explanation for why this is happening will be much appreciated.

Does this answer your question? Get top 1 row of each group

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/qsl9BhzZ

Using Thom A suggestions from
Get top 1 row of each group
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CompanyNo_PK  ORDER BY e.[DateHired] DESC) AS rn
    FROM  
        [Company] c 
    INNER JOIN 
        [Employee] e ON e.CompanyNo_FK = c.CompanyNo_PK 
                     AND JobRoleNo_FK = 1
)
SELECT CompanyName,     EmployeeName,   DateHired
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1

fiddle



CompanyName
EmployeeName
DateHired




Foo
Kathy
6/25/2022


Bar
Bob
1/9/2021


FooBar
Adam
8/3/2021




This is a little simpler, or at least uses more basic constructs only - no CTE's, no ROW_NUMBER/PARTITION OVER's, no APPLY's.
SELECT c.CompanyName, e.EmployeeName, e.DateHired
  FROM Company c
  LEFT JOIN Employee e
       ON e.CompanyNo_FK = c.CompanyNo_PK AND e.JobRoleNo_FK = 1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM #Employee e1
     WHERE e1.CompanyNo_FK = c.CompanyNo_PK
       AND e1.JobRoleNo_FK = 1
       AND e1.DateHired > e.DateHired);

To be clear though, this won't really cover the case where a company has no managers at all; the company will be unlisted.  If you want to avoid that and ensure that every company is represented in the final table, you'll need an OR clause after all (e.EmployeeNoPK IS NULL OR NOT EXISTS...)
